# What is a better: Giving a client scripts or a installable package if they plan on heavily editing?

Tags: node.js, package

I'm doing an a email marketing app for an ecommerce site for the first time using node.js amd I'm a newb. I fully expect the dev team to change a lot of the default times and add new email types in the immediate future.

Hence the title question...

I structured it as follows:

Multiple email scripts that are designed to be run by either cron or task scheduler:
So one script for running every 5 minutes, 10 minutes, 1 day, etc. Within each script is the code for the emails to be sent out after query to the user database finds a match within its time frame. Developer can add new time interval scripts and/or put multiple types of emails in any script.

I made a powershell and bash script for installing the node js dependencies and linking them so all the developer has to do is:

1. Extract tar (has existing email scripts, and email template folder)
2. run node dependecies script
3. Edit scripts to their desire (login info, database, email content, etc.)
4. go to cron/task scheduler; configure it to run any email scripts at scheduled time.

   - - - - node (location of relevant script)

I presented the first draft to the developer and he wondered why it wasn't configured as a package.
What would be the benefits of configuring it as a package versus giving them a collection of scripts in a tar file?

Answer (score 0):

Simplicity of setup is probably part of it. This kind of sounds like a good candidate for [node-webkit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit) which will allow you to create an easily distributed all-in-one application for OSX, Windows, and Linux. It would include node itself, a browser based interface, your servers, scripts, and anything you can come up with.

This approach would also give you a GUI where the configuration details can be configured from a simple form and whatever else you can imagine and develop out. For building releases for each platform, I would recommend checking out [grunt-node-webkit-builder](https://github.com/mllrsohn/grunt-node-webkit-builder).